# GSAP/SVG setting x/y origin based on active tab, and looping through event listeners

Tags: javascript, css, svg, gsap

I am working on a doughnut circle svg with expanding tabs. As of last night the expanding tabs are fully functional and the correct x/y transform is applied on mouseenter/mouseleave. (the x/y is essential on both mouse enter and mouse leave for proper transform origin - this was difficult to get each tab expansion to appear centered as it is a circle).

Today I have tried going further with the project by creating an additional loop that displays corresponding content based on the active tab index. (This is working).

Now I want to go a step further by making the current tab stay expanded until another tab is hovered over. Right now the eventlistener mouseleave applies when my mouse leaves the tab (obviously). What can I do to keep the current tab "active" unless hovering over another tab? (rather than the mouseleave?). I am still fairly inexperienced with JS, I'll be content if anyone could just send me in the right direction

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/jpark197/pen/LYOEbgz)

```
const subTabs = gsap.utils.toArray(".subtab");
const expandTabs = gsap.utils.toArray(".expandtab");

// Timeline set default duration to .025
const tl = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { duration: 0.025 } });

tl.set(expandTabs, {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 0.5,
    x: "0%",
    y: "0%",
});

// display corresponding content based on active tab
// Set expand tab x/y when inactive
let tabIndex = 1;
    tabExcerpt(tabIndex);


function currentTab(n) {
    tabExcerpt(tabIndex = n);
}

function tabExcerpt(n) {
    let i;
    let expandTab = document.querySelectorAll(".expandtab");
    let tabExcerpts = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-excerpt");

    if (n > tabExcerpts.length) {tabIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {tabIndex = tabExcerpts.length}
    for (i = 0; i < tabExcerpts.length; i++) {
        tabExcerpts[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < expandTab.length; i++) {
        // Need to set expand tab to default x/y when not active
        expandTab[i] = (num) => {
            tl.set(expandTab, {
                scale: 0.5,
                opacity: 0,
                x: "25%",
                y: "25%",
            });
        }
    }
    tabExcerpts[tabIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    // expandTab[tabIndex-1].className.baseVal += " active";
}

subTabs.forEach((subTab, index) => {
    let expandTab = expandTabs[index];

    // Event Listener Hover On
    // If index[0]
    if (index === 0) {
        subTabs[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
            console.log("you entered region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "30%",
                    y: "25%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                }
            );
        });
    } else if (index === 1) {
        subTabs[1].addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
            console.log("you entered region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "24%",
                    y: "39%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                }
            );
        });
    } else if (index === 2) {
        subTabs[2].addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
            console.log("you entered region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "25%",
                    y: "25%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                }
            );
        });
    } else if (index === 3) {
        subTabs[3].addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
            console.log("you entered region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "25%",
                    y: "25%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                }
            );
        });
    } else if (index === 4) {
        subTabs[4].addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
            console.log("you entered region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "25%",
                    y: "25%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                }
            );
        });
    }

    // Event Listener Hover off
    // if index[0]
    if (index === 0) {
        subTabs[0].addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
            console.log("you exited region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "35%",
                    y: "25%",
                }
            );
        });
    } else if (index === 1) {
        subTabs[1].addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
            console.log("you exited region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "24%",
                    y: "39%",
                }
            );
        });
    } else if (index === 2) {
        subTabs[2].addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
            console.log("you exited region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "25%",
                    y: "25%",
                }
            );
        });
    } else if (index === 3) {
        subTabs[3].addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
            console.log("you exited region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "25%",
                    y: "25%",
                }
            );
        });
    } else if (index === 4) {
        subTabs[4].addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
            console.log("you exited region number " + index);
            tl.fromTo(
                expandTab,
                {
                    scale: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: "0%",
                    y: "0%",
                },
                {
                    scale: 0.5,
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: "25%",
                    y: "25%",
                }
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello! It's me again. You had some changes in the HTML for sure... Can you provide a codepen like yesterday?

Comment: Yes! Hi again! Setting up code pen now-

Comment: code pen is up - note: the content moves a lot when hovering because I set up flex display- I will worry about this later

Comment: Okay... I got it... Hold on.

Comment: Thats why better create snippet inside SO not Codepen. You codepen example was deleted, and any other user SO can't check it. Why did you dont place like your code to the SO snippet? this question is no longer of value to the community

Comment: There is a forked codepen in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `mouseout` event here, you will have to use a "custom event".

Yes, you can create events... Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) and dispatch them. That allows you to trigger something special without interfering with the "normal behavior" of any other regular event.

Below, I called the event "retract". Yay! You also can name it like you wish!

Here is the function:

```
function unhover(exceptIndex){
  subTabs[exceptIndex].classList.add("expanded")
  subTabs.forEach((subTab, index) => {
    if(index != exceptIndex && subTab.classList.contains("expanded")){
      let event = new Event('retract');
      subTab.dispatchEvent(event);
      subTab.classList.remove("expanded");
    }
  })
}
```

Andd you will call it at the end of each `mouseenter` callbacks, passing the index of the currently hovered one (because that one should not retract).

```
unhover(index);
```

Here is your [CodePen forked and edited](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ExbaNGZ?editors=0010)

Nice (and fast!) work about the expanding, by the way! Keep on the good job. ;)

Comment: I just noticed a really tiny glitch... Just add `&& !subTab.classList.contains("expanded")` to all the `if` conditions like `if (index === 0) {` for the `mouseenter` events... That will remove the tiny weird movement when entering an already expanded tab.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You really helped send me in the right direction yesterday. Very cool stuff with the event creation, excited to read about it!

Comment: Thanks for the warning! Fixing now